# "Superset Docker Setup: Invalid Login Credentials Popup Issue. Unable to access dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

I attempted to set up Superset on my machine using Docker and WSL Ubuntu. After executing the command `docker-compose up` in the terminal and accessing the login page, I encountered an issue. When entering the default login credentials:

- Username: admin
- Password: admin

A popup appeared, indicating invalid login credentials. Consequently, I am unable to access the dashboard. Can anyone provide assistance with resolving this issue?

i have tried restarting the docker and wsl machin